# socket.io and sails js issue accessing get request query string

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, sails.js

I am sorry if this question has been asked before in the forum but I am not able to find what I am looking for. I am looking to develop a notification mechanism in my sails js app.

Taking the analogy of facebook, lets say we have users and pages.

Users can follow other users

Users can like a page

If a user A is following user B, then user A must get notifications from User B's activity. 
For example, if user B likes a page, User a must be notified.

I saw [this tutorial](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/10/10/building-a-sails-application-ep21-integrating-socket-dot-io-and-sails-with-custom-controller-actions-using-real-time-model-events/) for sockets.io which was quite helpful to get me started. The thing is that in this tutorial, the person is subscribing only to the User collection. If anything changes in that collection for the specified user, then the subscriber is notified. I want to selectively subscribe to a particular user

For this, I was trying to provide a query string with socket.get request

For example

```
socket.get('/user/subscribe?followee=2');
```

The problem I am running into is that when I try to access the query string in the controller, I don't see the followee param or any other param.

```
sails.log.debug(req.params.all());
```

shows an empty object.

**EDIT:** I was doing a lot of hit and trial and observed one thing but not sure I understood it correctly. If I disable actions in the config/controllers.js and create a route manually in routes.js

```
'get /subscribe': 'UserController.subscribe',
```

then it works.